# moving user by gps and show interested points

Tags: postgresql, javascript, web-mapping, google-maps-api

Is it possible in a Web application with google maps, to use a user his mobile gps and when move and is near on an interest point such as hotels, interested point i have stored in a Postgresql database, to show it in map.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at leaflet maps - gps plugin (http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-gps/)

It automatically updates the gps location received from the device (html5 geolocation).

I suppose you can attach a javascript to that updating event, to look up any POI's within a certain buffer around that gps point. These POI's can then be fed back into the leafletmap through geoJSON.

Hope that can get you on the right track.

Comment: I can use only google maps , ican't use leaflet maps.